# std::list<>: Element before l.begin()

Tags: c++, list

Short question: Is the following code unsafe using other compilers than I do (mingw32), or is it valid to use?

```
list<int> l;
/* add elements */
list<int>::iterator i = l.begin();
i--;
i++;
cout << *i << endl;
```

...or in other words:  is `i` defined to point to `l.begin()` after this?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the code is unsafe. Once you attempt to move before `begin()` you have caused *undefined behavior*. Attempting to move "back again" may not work.

Comment: That would be fine as long as your list is not empty. You would be at the last "real" element in the list. ++list.end() would be undefined.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: `list.end()` is not an lvalue so that's not well formed. You can decrement an iterator pointing to `list.end()` if and only if the list is not empty.

Comment: @Vanessa and Charles I think `list.end()` points to the iterator just past the last real element, which is why you can do `while (i != l.end())`, right? So why can you do `i=l.end(); --i;`

Comment: Note that the standardese backing up this (correct) answer is in §24.1.4/1 for C++03 and §24.2.6/1 for the C++0x FDIS.

Comment: @Seth: `l.end()` is a valid iterator, even though it does not refer to a real element and cannot be dereferenced. The result of decrementing `l.begin()` is not a valid iterator.

Comment: @ildjarn: Wow! How did you get your hands on a copy of C++11? That's amazing! Especially since it hasn't even been published yet...

Comment: @Tomalak : Well, if it doesn't end up getting published this year, then I'll give you a free cookie. Fair? ;-] (Real answer: now that the `c++0x` tag is permanently a synonym for the `c++11` tag, it seems consistent to call C++0x 'C++11' in all scenarios.)

Comment: @ildjarn: Not the point! It doesn't exist and you cannot actually have referenced it! :D

Comment: @Seth: He's not. And you've missed my point; quoting the FDIS is fair game, but quoting something that doesn't physically exist yet is not! [Even though we know the wording will be the same.]

Comment: @Tomalak: He can have a reference alright, it's just that if he dereferences it, he'll cite and undefined standard.

Answer (score 2):

A std::list traverses its contents via linked list pointers, so pointer arithmetic is not used to calculate a correct position.  The previous position from .begin() will have no data and shouldn't provide any valid traversal mechanisms.

Containers like std::vector have random access iterators and would use pointer arithmetic under the covers, so they would probably give the right result (no problem), but its still a bad idea.

So, it shouldn't work, its undefined, and don't do it even if it does work somehow :)

Comment: Linked lists and pointers are a complete implementation detail.

Comment: Iterators of containers like `std::vector<>` are still subject to the rules regarding bidirectional+ iterators in the standard, which specifically says this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I agree on both comments - its undefined, and linked lists are an implementation detail.  But it probably wouldn't work in his case because its almost certaintly a linked list, and the biderectional iterator most likely uses pointer arithmetic for the vector, so that should allow movement past the ends.  It's against the standard and bad to assume these things though, but I thought they'd be nice for him to consider.  Appologies if I added some confusion! :(